# Video on bootstrap modal popup continues playing audio after closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, audio

I have a very basic you tube video playing on a bootstrap modal popup window. When I press close, the video itself closes but the audio continues to play. Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks!!

```
                                          <div class="modal fade" id="tvDebutPlay" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModal" aria-hidden="true">
                                          <div class="modal-dialog2">
                                              <div class="modal-content2">
                                                  <div class="modal-body2">
                                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default st-closeBtn" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
                                                      <div>
                                                          <iframe width="100%" height="480" src=""></iframe>
                                                      </div>
                                                  </div>
                                              </div>
                                          </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the modal is being hidden but not destroyed so there is nothing to stop it from playing in the background. You can get around this with a bit of jQuery.

Something along the lines of:

```
var modal = $('.modal-dialog2');
modal.find('.st-bloseBtn').click(function() {
   modal.remove();
});
```

if you need to allow it to appear again then I suggest you create a clone of it before letting the document show it in the first place (i.e. before it autoplays)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your reply. I actually just got it working using a different method. In case anyone else has similar problems I simply added this click event which removes the source of the iframe:

$('.st-closeBtn').click(function(){

$('iframe').attr('src', '');

});

Comment: I use this way as well. There is probably a more efficient way instead of removing the src from the DOM, but does the job!

Answer (score 1):

I saw this on a blog and it works perfect (https://medium.com/@webnotes/stop-vimeo-video-playing-in-background-after-bootstrap-modal-close-c076215a8a1b):

Basically you need the event when the modal closes and set the src property to empty string. And that event name is `hidden.bs.modal`

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
var $this = $(this);
//get iframe on click
var vidsrc_frame = $this.find("iframe");
var vidsrc_src = vidsrc_frame.attr('src');
console.log(`videosrc=` + vidsrc_src)
vidsrc_frame.attr('src', '');
vidsrc_frame.attr('src', vidsrc_src);
});
```